# Qt - compiler won't recognize "connect"

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm working in Qt 4.7, and I have a portion of code with signals and slots. It's set up just as normal, namely:

```
#include <QObject>

//Earlier code...
connect(my_thread, SIGNAL(started()), other_thread, SLOT(process()));
connect(my_thread, SIGNAL(finished()), third_thread, SLOT(some_slot()));
//Later code...
```

However, when I build it gives an error for each statement saying "C3861: 'connect': identifier not found" Does anyone have any ideas why this may be? Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you use connect in code that is not part of a `QObject` derived class, precede the connect with the `QObject::`, so the code will become:

```
//Earlier code...
QObject::connect(my_thread, SIGNAL(started()), other_thread, SLOT(process()));
```

LE: basically you call the static *connect* method and when you are not in the scope of a QObject (or a QObject derived class) you need to fully specify the *connect* you want to call, else the compiler doesn't find it (or it might find a wrong connect in the current scope)

Comment: Is it fine to use `connect` in a class that does not derive from `QObject`?

Comment: @Ayxan yes it is fine. The connection can be made from anywhere you have access to the 2 objects you need to connect, probably that is why the _connect_ function is a static member function of the QObject class.